# How to count the no of lines in a particular cell in a table column through PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Oracle >> How to count the no of lines entered in a cell in table, because i want to restrict maximum line for a customer. friends kindly give some suggestions to execute this command with SQL and PL/SQL..

Comment: can you give some more clarity about your question, then only we can try to help you,

Comment: actually i'm using oracle apex, in oracle apex page i put a text area for description column. so i want to count the no of lines entered in this particular text area. through oracle..please suggest me

Comment: Do you want to check how many actual lines are used (newline characters)? Not how many characters in total? What if the user just types all info in one long line (which evidently gets wordwrapped in the textarea control and thus looks like newlines...)?

Comment: yes Tom, i want to count the no lines user entered in a text box,  at the same time i want restrict the line if user entered more than 10 lines. at the same i fixed the no of characters to enter in a text area. Thanks Tom

Comment: So you want to restrict the number of line feed or carriage return characters in the string?

Comment: yes want to restrict the text line if the user enter more than 10 no of line

Comment: what kind of ítem are you using to input the string?

Comment: i'am using text area typo...

Answer (score 0):

Create a validation on that page that runs when query exists.
Add this query changing `P1_item` with the name of your page item:

`SELECT 1 from dual where length(:P1_item) - length(REPLACE(:P1_item, chr(10), ''))>10`

Using this when you submit the page if there are more than 10 new lines in your page item the validation will popup an error.